# Trouble with parsing XML Attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm pretty new to jquery xml parsing and have hit a wall.
I have an XML source data file like this called tracker2.xml (very simple):

```
<spotter num="17555" report_at="2013-01-29 04:05:17" lat="45.0463562" lng="-93.4922943"></spotter>
```

I am trying to pull "lat", "lng", and "report_at" as variables to use later in the code.  I have this so far and to me seems to be the proper code.  I added the alert(report_at) to troubleshoot.  When run, the alert displays "[object]".

```
    $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "tracker2.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: parseXml
   });
 });
function parseXml(xml)
 {
   $(xml).find('spotter').each(function()
   {
     var report_at = $(this).attr('report_at');
     var lats = $(this).attr('lat');
     var lngs = $(this).attr('lng');
   });
}
alert(report_at);
```

I'm sure i am missing something stupid.  Anyone that can help me will be my hero.  Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure about the 'report_at alert'? This would normally cause an undefined error because you declare the variable inside the parseXML function. Is this just a copy&paste mistake? If not try to put the alert inside the function parseXML and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function parseXml(xml)
 {
   $(xml).find('spotter').each(function()
   {
     var report_at = $(this).attr('report_at');
     var lats = $(this).attr('lat');
     var lngs = $(this).attr('lng');
alert(report_at);
   });
}
```

you are alert the `report_at` variable out of your for loop, try it inside your loop

Comment: I tried moving it inside of the function and the alert still shows.  Also, when calling the variable later in the script, I get the same "[object]" returned.  Maybe I am assigning the variables incorrectly?  will these not be global variables?

Comment: Ok.  Check that last comment.  It looks like it does alert to correct variable.  How do I return those variables out of the function to the main script?  I guess this is my problem.

Comment: @PaulW create the array of those variables and return it to your main function. like this Mainfunction(arrayReport, arrayLats, arrayLngs);